# Conveying to someone through eMail that they are the one millionth customer of my product without sounding suspicious

Tags: style, business-writing, email

Say I owned a website, game, product, etc. and wanted to tell someone by eMail that they are the one millionth customer of mine, and maybe even promise them a reward.

The problem is that eMails of this nature are known by many to be suspicious. The eMails could get picked up by spam filters or manually deleted by people who ignore the messages, assuming someone is trying to scam them.

How do I write an eMail message that genuinely conveys this message and won't be passed off as illegitimate by the reader?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Questions asking what to write are off-topic here, but I *think* this can be answered simply by providing some techniques you could use rather than just writing the email for you.

Comment: **You should announce the raffle in your social media, on your site *before* sign up or purchase, and upon sign up, then people are prepared for the message and the exact wording no longer matters.** Also, you need to also consider that in some jurisdictions you are forbidden to send advertising email to someone unless they explicitly signed up to receive them. Even if that is not the law where you are, people react poorly to being spammed, so make sure your users agree to receive emails *and to partake in the raffle* when they sign up or purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put any links in it!

As scammers hope to get people to click on links to trap them on dodgy websites, spam filters check for links.  Also, no images called in from a website.  These look like trackers to a filter.

Not just filters, but many of your customers will be suspicious of any links for the same reasons.

A message that is simple text, maybe with images embedded in the email, stands much more chance of being read.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the announce on your social media, something like:

Notice one, may be on Monday:

*"Remember our XYZ contest? The winner will be announced this Friday. Stay Tunned."*

Friday Notice:
*"There's a winner of our contest and we sent them an email today. The winner's emails is Sxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com" (just first leter and ending). Does this appy to you? Check your inbox to find out if you are the lucky one!"*

You should have sent the email minutes before publishing this announce, to make sure that the winner finds it. As someone say, don't include a link on the email message.

The email text could say something like:

*"Congrats, NAME! You won the contest XYZ because REASON. Please email John Doe at john.doe@yoursitedomain.com to ask for instructions about claiming your prize. This notice will be announced in our social media channels today, check them out."*

Make it short, simple. When the winner goes to your social media channels, they will see there are great chances to be real. Hopefully, they will write to you.